# Synchronize when updating the UI in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wcf, response

I have written a application that must connect to a WCF service. The connection to the WCF Service form the android device is done in a `AsyncTask`. To update the main UI I have to Synchronize. The way that I am Currently calling the Thread is 
`new ServiceRun().execute("http://10.0.0.14/serv/UserManagement.svc/ping")`. The problem with doing this is that when I want to display the response from the JSON WCF Service (`txt.setText(svcR.execute("http://10.0.0.14/serv/UserManagement.svc/register/test/test/test/test/test").toString());`) I get the Object's memory address `com.example.wcf.ServiceRun@41f8a470` instead of displaying `ServerPinged`.

```
public class ServiceRun extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private Exception exception;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String msg="";
        try 
        {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               URI uri = new URI(url[0]); 

                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
                httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                Log.i( "login", "received " + getResponse(response.getEntity()) );
                msg=getResponse(response.getEntity());


        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;
    }

    private String getResponse( HttpEntity entity )
    {
      String response = "";

      try
      {
        int length = ( int ) entity.getContentLength();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( length );
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( entity.getContent(), "UTF-8" );
        char buff[] = new char[length];
        int cnt;
        while ( ( cnt = isr.read( buff, 0, length - 1 ) ) > 0 )
        {
          sb.append( buff, 0, cnt );
        }

          response = sb.toString();
          isr.close();
      } catch ( IOException ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      }

      return response;
    }



}
```

What causes this to happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: com.example.wcf.ServiceRun.toString() returns `com.example.wcf.ServiceRun@41f8a470`  which is normal Object.toString() implementation... do not repost the question!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911529/displaying-the-response-form-wcf-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you want to update your UI with the results of the AsyncTask, and it won't work. You update the UI by overriding the onProgressUpdate() and onPostExecute() methods in your AsyncTask.

Comment: What do you mean with this? Must I place the connection to WCF in the do in background and in `onPostExecute` place the UI update for the TextView?

Comment: Exactly as you said. If you want to pass updates to the UI partway through the background process, override onProgressUpdate.  If you just need to pass back the result at the end, just override onPostExecute. Since your UI is in a different class, you'll probably want to pass a listener into your AsyncTask so that onPostExecute can call it to report back to the UI. Alternatively you can make your AsyncTask an inner class inside of the class where your UI resides so that you can just directly update the UI elements in onPostExecute.

Comment: I will do that. Will let you know of the outcome